# pyspark conditionally parse fixed width text file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, fixed-width

So I have a fixed width file and I won't know its format until a certain variable in it is check if a certain variable is '01' or '02'. So I am trying to create something like this:

```
myreport= spark.read.text("/mnt/path/mydata")
myreport= myreport.select(myreport.value.substr(1,3).alias('client'),
myreport.value.substr(4,2).alias('rptnum'),
if rptnum = '01', then
myreport.value.substr(6,2).cast('integer').alias('mo1'),
myreport.value.substr(8,2).cast('integer').alias('mo2'),
myreport.value.substr(12,2).cast('integer').alias('mo3'),
Else
myreport.value.substr(6,2).cast('integer').alias('mo1'),
myreport.value.substr(8,2).cast('integer').alias('mo2'),
myreport.value.substr(12,2).cast('integer').alias('mo3'),
myreport.value.substr(14,2).cast('integer').alias('mo4'),
myreport.value.substr(16,2).cast('integer').alias('mo5'),
myreport.value.substr(18,2).cast('integer').alias('mo6'),
```

Basically the number of columns doubles if the rpt number isn't 01. Pretty unsure how to do this in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

You would to write function which would be called from `df.rdd.map()` and transform/parse each line. You can create same number of columns but in one case, some of the columns would be null. Using `filter()` on the rptnum, you can separate out the rows and select the respective columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *

def transformRow(row):
    value = row['value']
    client = value[1:4]
    rptnum = value[4:6]
    rowDict = {'client': client, 'rptnum': rptnum,'mo1': None,'mo2': None,'mo3': None,'mo4': None,'mo5': None,'mo6': None}
    rowDict['mo1'] = value[6:8]
    rowDict['mo2'] = value[8:10]
    rowDict['mo3'] = value[10:12]

    if rptnum != '01' :
        rowDict['mo4'] = value[12:14]
        rowDict['mo5'] = value[14:16]
        rowDict['mo6'] = value[16:18]
    return Row(**rowDict)

myreport= spark.read.text("/mnt/path/mydata")
myreport = myreport.rdd.map(transformRow).toDF()

rpt1 = myreport.filter(col("rptnum") == '01').select("mo1","mo2","mo3")
rpt2 = myreport.filter(col("rptnum") != '01')
```